# arithmetic operation in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

How can I find the greatest 2 numbers out of 3 numbers and perform some arithmetic operations on them like in following example?

```
<root>
    <num>10</num>
    <num>12</num>
    <num>8</num>
</root>
```

For the above input the xslt code should display "10 + 12 = 22" and "average = 11".

Comment: This sounds like homework.  SO people tend to ignore "give me the answer" type questions.  What have you tried?  Show what you've done and what isn't working.

Comment: @Jim Garrisson: i don know how to do arithmetic operations in xslt!!!
this is not my home work.

Comment: @Jim Garrisson: my problem is much bigger. i have given just a small snippet of code for example. and i am not a school kid!!!

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for two complete solutions: in XSLT 1.0 and in XSLT 2.0.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:template match="/root">
        <xsl:variable name="max1" select="num[not(../num > .)]"/>
        <xsl:variable name="max2" select="num[not(../num[count(.|$max1)!=1] > .)]"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat($max1,' + ',
                                     $max2,' = ',
                                     $max1 + $max2,'&#xA;',
                                     'average = ',
                                     ($max1 + $max2) div 2,'&#xA;')"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
12 + 10 = 22
average = 11
```

Answer (score 10):

**I. XSLT 1.0 solution**

**This transformation finds the sum and average of all numbers except those with the minimal value** -- works for a nodeset of numbers of any length:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vMin">
  <xsl:for-each select="/*/num">
   <xsl:sort data-type="number"/>
   <xsl:if test="position()=1">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
   </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:variable>

 <xsl:variable name="vNumsWithoutMin" select="/*/num[not(.=$vMin)]"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vSumWithoutMin" select="sum($vNumsWithoutMin)"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="$vNumsWithoutMin"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="concat(' = ', $vSumWithoutMin)"/>
  average = <xsl:value-of select=
  "$vSumWithoutMin div count($vNumsWithoutMin)"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="num">
   <xsl:value-of select="."/>
   <xsl:if test="not(position()=last())">
     <xsl:text> + </xsl:text>
   </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<root>
    <num>10</num>
    <num>12</num>
    <num>8</num>
</root>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
10 + 12 = 22
average = 11
```

**II. XSLT 2.0 solution**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vMin" select="min(/*/num/number(.))"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vNumsSansMin"
  select="/*/num[not(number() eq $vMin)]/number(.)"/>
 <xsl:variable name="vAvgSansMin"
      select="avg($vNumsSansMin)"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:sequence select=
     "(for $i in 1 to count($vNumsSansMin)
        return
         ($vNumsSansMin[$i],
          if(not($i eq count($vNumsSansMin)))
            then ' + '
            else ()
          )
      ),
      ' = ', sum($vNumsSansMin)
     "/>

     average = <xsl:sequence select="$vAvgSansMin"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```